# How to resolve quote issue in mysql php prepare statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql prepare statement in a PHP script as such:

```
$stmt = $ln_sph->prepare("SELECT (CASE WHEN n.Id IS NULL THEN e.ExclusionEn ELSE concat(e.ExclusionEn, ' (', n.TitleEn, ' (', n.Naics, '))') END) AS Exclusion 
                FROM tblExclusion e 
                LEFT JOIN tblNaics n ON (e.ExclusionClassNaicsId = n.Id) 
                WHERE NaicsId = :Id");
$stmt->bindValue(':match', $search_query, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$docs = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

I would like to modify query in the prepare statement to handle this query...

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN n.Id IS NULL THEN e.ExclusionEn ELSE concat(e.ExclusionEn, ' (','(<a href="javascript:__displayDetails(' ,e.ExclusionClassNaicsId,',1);">',n.TitleEn, ' (', n.Naics, ')</a>)') END) AS Exclusion 
                    FROM tblExclusion e 
                    LEFT JOIN tblNaics n ON (e.ExclusionClassNaicsId = n.Id) 
                    WHERE NaicsId = :Id
```

I can run this query just fine directly within mysql but I don't know how to get it in the prepare statement due to the quotes.  I think the bindValue might be of use but have not had any luck with it.  Any help or point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You can escape the double-quotes by using `\"` inside of the string.

Comment: `WHERE NaicsId = :Id` yet you used `:match`. Either that was a typo, or the question is unclear. *"I have a mysql prepare statement in a PHP script as such"* - Which will not work, as posted. Can you respond to this comment, or have you left the question/logged off?

Comment: and why was this tagged as mysqli when you're using PDO named placeholders? Edit: To which that was changed to `mysql` in an edit.

Comment: yes sorry the :match should actually be :Id...I was cutting and pasting from a couple of sources and cut & pasted the wrong one.  Everything else is correct.  I am green at all this...thought mysqli was the php interface to mysql.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

First break up the SQL into a separate variable. Makes the code cleaner and easier to debug:

```
$sql = 'SELECT (CASE WHEN n.`Id` IS NULL THEN e.`ExclusionEn` ELSE concat(e.`ExclusionEn`, \' (\',\'(<a href="javascript:__displayDetails(\' ,e.`ExclusionClassNaicsId`,\',1);">\',n.`TitleEn`, \' (\', n.`Naics`, \')</a>)\') END) AS Exclusion 
        FROM `tblExclusion` AS e 
        LEFT JOIN `tblNaics` AS n ON (e.`ExclusionClassNaicsId` = n.`Id`) 
        WHERE `NaicsId` = :Id';
```

then you can var_dump to see how it comes out for use and see where it goes wrong.

Other note: You can replace `\'` with `"` - but I'm a single-quote fan :)

After that, chuck it into the prepare statement:
`$stmt = $ln_sph->prepare($sql);`